# How to read the hyper-link of an image in power Point using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, ms-office, office-interop

I have inserted an image to powerpoint using c# and have inserted a hyperlink to the picture and its working perfectly.But now i need to read the hyperlink of that picture which i have inserted using c#.

Whereas am inserting a text with hyperlink into powerpoint using c# ,and am reading the hyperlink back from the powerpoint by the below method.

```
for (int i = 0; i < presentation.Slides.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (var item in presentation.Slides[i + 1].Shapes)
            {
                var shape = (PPT.Shape)item;
                if (shape.HasTextFrame == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
                {
                    if (shape.TextFrame.HasText == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
                    {
                        var textRange = shape.TextFrame.TextRange;
                        var text = textRange.Text;

                        string address=textRange.ActionSettings[PPT.PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Hyperlink.Address;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

where am getting the hyperlink address in the variable **address**, likewise i need to get the hyperlink from the image which i have inserted into PPT using c#.

Is it possible.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to iterate through Shapes on a Slide and see, whether they contain hyperlink. Or you should give your picture an id when creating it and then find it by the given id.

```
    private void GetHyperlink()
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application objApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
        objApp.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
        Presentations objPresSet = objApp.Presentations;
        Presentation p = objPresSet.Open("C:\test.ppt");
        Slide slide = p.Slides[1];
        // or Slide slide = objApp.ActiveWindow.View.Slide;

        for (int i = 1; i <= slide.Shapes.Count; i++)
        {
            //If the hyperlink address is filled then display it in MessageBox
            if (slide.Shapes[i].ActionSettings[PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Hyperlink.Address != null)
                MessageBox.Show(slide.Shapes[i].ActionSettings[PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Hyperlink.Address);
        }
    }
```

This code will display all hyperlinks on slide 1.
Also it would be interesting to use Open XML SDK for this purpose instead of automation.

Interesting link:

http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/slidesnet/Finding+a+Shape+in+a+Slide

### EDIT:

I suggest you first modify the code that creates the image with hyperlink like this:

```
        //Add a picture
        Shape pic = slide.Shapes.AddPicture(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\koala.jpg",
        Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
        Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue,
        shape.Left, shape.Top, shape.Width, shape.Height);

        //Here you have various options how to distinguish your shape
        pic.Name = "MyPic";
        pic.AlternativeText = "Koala";
        pic.Tags.Add("MyPic", "@http://www.google.com/");

        //adding hyperlink, etc...
        pic.ActionSettings[PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Hyperlink.Address =@"http://www.google.com/"
```

Then when you read the file you can use tags or name to distinguish shapes:

```
            //tags check
            if (slide.Shapes[i].Tags.Count > 0 && slide.Shapes[i].Tags["MyPic"]!=null && slide.Shapes[i].ActionSettings[PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Hyperlink.Address != null)
                MessageBox.Show(slide.Shapes[i].ActionSettings[PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Hyperlink.Address);
            //or
            //name check
            if (slide.Shapes[i].Name.Equals("MyPic", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && slide.Shapes[i].ActionSettings[PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Hyperlink.Address != null)
                MessageBox.Show(slide.Shapes[i].ActionSettings[PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Hyperlink.Address);
```

Comment: @vDhhnal : but it may also shows the hyperlink of others also na.?

Comment: Yes, you must first find the proper shape by its ID and then you can easily get the hyperlink.

Comment: but how to i differntiate the shape between textframe and diagram

Comment: ya okie i will give a try to this.

Comment: @Arshad - For textframe i guess the HasTextFrame property will be true. You can check for which shapes this property is false...

Comment: @VDohnal have some doubts,can you please help me..!

Comment: @VDohnal  can you please help me in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094014/replacing-images-in-power-point-using-c-sharp]