# Replacing images in power point using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, powerpoint, office-addins

In in powerpoint i have placed some diagrams diagrams, where each diagram contains different guid.And i have set the GUID as their hyperlink. when the refresh button is clicked what i do is ,will find the shape and then  will get the guid which i have saved as hyperlink for each image , from each image and using that GUID will replace the recent image with the old image in that shape.

```
foreach (var shape in presentation.Slides[slideno].Shapes)
                {
                    var slide = (PPT.Slide)item;
                    if (j <= shapeCount)
                    {
                        string[] address = new string[] { };
                        string dskj = slide.Shapes[j].Name;
                        if (slide.Shapes[j].Name.Equals("DIAGRAM")//, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                         && slide.Shapes[j].ActionSettings[PPT.PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Hyperlink.Address != null)
                        {
                            address = slide.Shapes[j].ActionSettings[PPT.PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Hyperlink.Address.Split('*');
                            string Type = address[0];
                            string Guid = address[1];
                            if (Type == "D")
                            {
                                Session.path = presentation.Path;
                                if (Session.path != "")
                                    Session.Repository.GetProjectInterface().PutDiagramImageToFile(address[1], Session.path + "\\" + address[1] + ".jpg", 1);
                                bool diagrm = false;
                                try
                                {
                                    EA.Diagram diag = Session.Repository.GetDiagramByGuid(Guid);
                                    diagrm = true;
                                }
                                catch
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                if (diagrm)
                                {
                                    float Shapeleft = slide.Shapes[j].Left;
                                    float Shapetop = slide.Shapes[j].Top;
                                    float Shapewidth = slide.Shapes[j].Width;
                                    float Shapeheight = slide.Shapes[j].Height;


                                    slide.Shapes[j].Delete();

                                    PPT.Shape pic = slide.Shapes.AddPicture(Session.path + "\\" + Guid + ".jpg", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                                     Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, Shapeleft, Shapetop, Shapewidth, Shapeheight);
                                    pic.Name = "DIAGRAM";
                                    pic.ActionSettings[PPT.PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Hyperlink.Address = "D*" + Guid;

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

using this above code everything works great.

```
address = slide.Shapes[j].ActionSettings[PPT.PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Hyperlink.Address
```

in address i will get the hyperlink address of that current image,but now my problem is if i have two images in a same single slide , then both the time when it loops inside the shapes it only gives the same hyperlink for both the images.

**NOTE:**If i have only one image in a slide then everything works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you're deleting the previous shape and inserting a new shape at the same place , but each shape contains a ZOrderPosition , where because of you deleted the previous and inserted a new shape the Zorderposition get changed for the new shape and it will be included in the next iteration.So if more than one image is inserted in a shape it only refrsh some images .
**SOLUTION**:

After deleting the existing and when inserting a new shape set its ZorderPosition also.

```
  pic.ZOrder(MsoZOrderCmd.msoSendToBack);
```

Hope it works..!!